# Bulma Override variable

Tags: html, css, webpack, bulma

I am creating a website using `webpack`, and have used a tile from `bulma`. I am attempting to change the basic formatting of the tile, such as the background colour, the tile-size etc, but I am struggling to find a way to override bulma's default settings for these.

I followed a YT tutorial, creating a `mystyle.scss` file with the variables (color, fonts etc) to override. This `.scss` is located in my dist directory, inside a `sass` folder, I tried to add it to the `@imports` of my sass files that are using the Bulma framework, this was supposed to override bulma's variables. Unfortunately, the code does not compile, I tried unsuccessfully importing the file using the following paths:

```
@import "sass/mystyle.scss"
@import "../sass/mystyle.scss"
@import "src/sass/mystyle"
@import "../src/sass/mystyle.scss"
@import "mystyle.css"
```

html:

```
<section class="contacts">
        <div>
            <title> Contact Us</title>
        </div>

        <div class="tile is-parent custom-tile" >
            <article class="tile is-child notification is-danger">
              <p class="title">Contact Us</p>
              <p class="subtitle">Please enter your details below, 
                  and we will try our best to get back to you as soon as possible.
                For enquiries about an appointment, please contact our surgery directly 
                on the telephone number provided.</p>

                <div class="content">
                <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">Name</label>
                    <div class="control">
                      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="e.g Alex Smith">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="field">
                    <label class="label">Email</label>
                    <div class="control">
                      <input class="input" type="email" placeholder="e.g. alexsmith@gmail.com">
                    </div>
                  </div>

                  <div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label class="label">Query</label>
                        <div class="control">
                          <textarea class="query info-box" placeholder="Please enter your query here"></textarea>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </article>
          </div>
        </div>


    </section>
```

css:

```
.custom-tile{
  background-color: blue($color: #000000);
  $body-background-color:   #29b5ff;
  $hr-background-color: #29b5ff;
}
```

Comment: Please edit into the question the code you have tried.

Comment: I have added it in @Zera

Comment: just import your scss AFTER your bulma

Comment: What do you mean after the bulma?

Comment: Please post the `<head>` section of your html.

Comment: you have to import bulma files. if you want to override their variables, just import your scss AFTER you import bulma scss

Comment: @Zera I have now updated the question

Comment: You do have a *`<head>`* section don't you? The part surrounded by `<head>` tags. Also, have you tried *alex067*'s solution?

Comment: @alex067 sorry I'm still not understanding sorry, could you explain it again?

Comment: @Zera I don't have a <head> section no

Comment: sorry @Naples my explanation was pretty simple and its basic css. Also, how do you not have a head section?

Comment: If you do not have a `<head>`, where do you import everything into the HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a css precedence issue. Make sure your order is correct otherwise the bluma styles will always take precedence

```
.class {background: red;}
.class {background: green;} /* I Win */
```

```
.class {background: red !important;} /* I Win */
.class {background: green;}
```

```
@import "bulma.css" 
@import "mystyle.css" /* I win when using the same selector */
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bulma.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css"> <!-- I win when using the same selector -->
```