# Bulma, how to change default media queries for classes throughout entire site

Tags: html, css, frameworks, bulma

For example, any is-4, is-7 etc. classes on columns only applies to the following rule by default. Using is-7 for instance..

```
@media screen and (min-width: 769px), print
.column.is-7, .column.is-7-tablet {
    flex: none;
    width: 58.33333%;
}
```

is-7 is an example, this also applies to is-2,is-3 and so forth

What i want to do is simply change min-width:769px to min-width:992px throughout every deafult rule

i tried to change the default $tablet variable to $992px BEFORE bulma is imported would work but this has not. $tablet is originally $769px so i thought this was the variable used to determine the min-width for those media queries

Does anyone know please?

Comment: Change the variable *after* the bulma import.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60214975/bulma-override-variable

Comment: i've just tried this, setting $tablet = 992px afterwards and nothing happens.. i think something else must determine the $769px in the media queiries then?

Comment: potentially yes, do a search across your solution to find all places where it is set

Comment: searching for 769 leads to no results in the bulma files unfortunately

Comment: is the css you posted using bulma variable at all?

Comment: i do not know exactly where that code comes from - when i check the class in inspect it shows that for any is-x class, but in the source code for bulma itself it does not have any reference to 769